# Set defaultValue via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this two components

```
<Field
  component={renderTextField} 
  id="jobTitle"
  label={t("field1")}
  name="jobTitle"
  required
  defaultValue={isOfferCopied ? job.jobName ? "Test"}
/>

export const renderTextField = (props) => {
  const {
    input,
    meta: { touched, invalid, error },
    endAdornment,
    ...restProps
  } = props;
  return (
    <TextField
      {...input}
      {...restProps}
      variant="outlined"
      error={touched && invalid}
      helperText={touched && error}
      InputProps={{ endAdornment }}
      // margin='dense'
    />
  );
};
```

Im triyng to send `defaultValue` prop in `Field` component, but the output is empty. How can i solve this?.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: @MridulGupta `defaultValue={isOfferCopied ? copiedJob.jobName : "test"}` its looking something like that, but the issue is, that `jobName` and `Test` are not showing

Comment: can you post the field component code ?

Comment: The `Field` is taken frow redux-forms, but here it is
 `export class Field<P extends GenericFieldHTMLAttributes | BaseFieldProps = GenericFieldHTMLAttributes | BaseFieldProps> extends Component<P> {
    dirty: boolean;
    name: string;
    pristine: boolean;
    value: any;
    getRenderedComponent(): Component<WrappedFieldProps & P>;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the default whole **Prop** object here:

`export const renderTextField = (props = { input = 'somedefaultInput', endAdornment = 'eye', meta = { touched: false, invalid: false, etc }) => {`

Or you can also default when you are defining the **const**

```
  const {
    input = 'someDefaultInput',
    meta: { touched, invalid, error } = { touched: false, invalid: false, error: null },
    endAdornment = 'eye',
    ...restProps
  } = props;
```

I also would highly recommend being explicit with the props that you are destructuring and avoid the `...restProps`

Comment: Its still shows empty output